# List of sheets should update when sheets are added, deleted, copied or changes name

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro ("List_of_sheets") that creates a list of all the sheets in the workbook, and places the list in the "Sheetlist"-sheet underneath the "Header"-word.

The macro deletes the previous list and creates a new list, whenever I run the macro. I do this manually whenever I delete, add, copy or change the name of sheet. However, I want this to run automatically.

Thanks in advance!

```
Sub List_of_sheets()
    Dim objSheet As Worksheet
    Dim intRow   As Integer
    Dim strCol   As Integer
    Dim GCell As Range

    SearchText = "Header"
    Set GCell = Worksheets("Listsheet").Cells.Find(SearchText).Offset(2, -1)

    GCell.End(xlDown).ClearContents

    intRow = GCell.Row
    strCol = GCell.Column

    For Each objSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Listsheet").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Listsheet").Cells(intRow, strCol), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "'" & objSheet.Name & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=objSheet.Name
            With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Listsheet").Cells(intRow, strCol).Font
                .Name = "Calibri"
                .FontStyle = "Normal"
                .Size = 11
                .Strikethrough = False
                .Superscript = False
                .Subscript = False
                .OutlineFont = False
                .Shadow = False
                .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
            End With
        intRow = intRow + 1
    Next objSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: The last time I had to create a Table of Contents, I ended up using the `BeforeSave` workbook event macro..............the only alternative was to use a separate macro to handle add/delete/modify worksheet names and have that separate macro build the TOC>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to go with Workbooks events, although they don't cover the case of a sheet name change

but as a workaround you could use `Workbook_SheetActivate` since when you change the name of a sheet and then you want to see if the list has been updated you *have* to activate the list sheet

so place in `ThisWorkbook` code pane the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    List_of_sheets
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    List_of_sheets
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

and you could consider the following refactoring of your code

```
Option Explicit

Sub List_of_sheets()
    Dim objSheet As Worksheet
    Dim intRow   As Integer
    Dim strCol   As Integer
    Dim GCell As Range
    Dim SearchText  As String

    SearchText = "Header"
    Set GCell = Worksheets("Listsheet").UsedRange.Find(what:=SearchText, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(2, -1)

    GCell.End(xlDown).ClearContents

    intRow = GCell.Row
    strCol = GCell.Column

    Dim listSheet As Worksheet
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Set listSheet = .Worksheets("Listsheet")
        For Each objSheet In .Sheets
            listSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=listSheet.Cells(intRow, strCol), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
            "'" & objSheet.Name & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=objSheet.Name
            intRow = intRow + 1
        Next objSheet
    End With
    With listSheet.Cells(GCell.Row, strCol).Resize(Sheets.Count).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Normal"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome. Of course this code will run EVERY time the user will switch between sheets. but that's the toll  to pay if you want such a running update

Comment: I'm willing to pay the toll, as the list of tables works as hyperlinks to the sheets, so I don't want to have to run the macro manually first, before being able to press the hyperlinks.
Again thanks!